# How can I make boost program options ignore certain inputs to be processed by another interpreter?

Tags: c++, boost, corba, boost-program-options

I'd like to use boost program options in a program I'm writing. This program also uses CORBA, which is designed to accept CORBA-specific command line inputs. I'd like to make boost program options ignore these CORBA-related command line inputs and only process the others. How can I accomplish this?

As an example, given the following command line:

```
./myprogram -ORBInitRef NameService=corbaloc:iiop:localhost:1234/NameService --myBoostOptionFoo 1 --myBoostOptionBar trololo
```

How can I make boost program options only process myBoostOptionFoo and myBoostOptionBar?

All CORBA command line inputs begin with "-ORBxxxxxx", so that should help with the filtering, but I'm completely lost as to whether or not there's an easy way to accomplish this, since boost::PO will complain about command line options it doesn't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight from the documentation on [Allowing Unknown Options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/program_options/howto.html#idp344642720):

> Usually, the library throws an exception on unknown option names. This
>   behavior can be changed. For example, only some part of your
>   application uses Program_options, and you wish to pass unrecognized
>   options to another part of the program, or even to another
>   application.
>
> To allow unregistered options on the command line, you need to use the
>   `basic_command_line_parser` class for parsing (not `parse_command_line`)
>   and call the `allow_unregistered method` of that class:

```
parsed_options parsed = command_line_parser(argc, argv).options(desc).allow_unregistered().run();
```

> For each token that looks like an option, but does not have a known
>   name, an instance of basic_option will be added to the result. The
>   string_key and value fields of the instance will contain results of
>   syntactic parsing of the token, the unregistered field will be set to
>   true, and the original_tokens field will contain the token as it
>   appeared on the command line.
>
> If you want to pass the unrecognized options further, the
>   `collect_unrecognized` function can be used. The function will collect
>   original tokens for all unrecognized values, and optionally, all found
>   positional options. Say, if your code handles a few options, but does
>   not handles positional options at all, you can use the function like
>   this:

```
vector<string> to_pass_further = collect_unrecognized(parsed.options,
include_positional);
```